# trouble sorting on last name with get_user()

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I would like my directory to sort by last name. How can I make this happen?

```
    function dispDirectory()
{
  global $user_ID;

  // Disallow directory if there is a messaging administrator and this person is not it.
  if ($this->admin_user_id && $this->admin_user_id != $user_ID) {
    return '';
  }

  $users = $this->get_users();
  $directory = "";


  foreach($users as $u)
  {
    $firstName = get_user_meta($u->ID, 'first_name', true);
    $lastName = get_user_meta($u->ID, 'last_name', true);         

    $directory .= '<p><strong>'.$lastName.', '.$firstName.'</strong> - <a href="'.$this->actionURL.'newmessage&to='.$u->ID.'">'.__('Send Message', 'cartpaujpm').'</a></p>';
  }
  return $directory;
}
```

To sort, I have tried adding the following before the foreach loop:

```
 usort($users, create_function('$a, $b', 'return strnatcasecmp($a->last_name, $b->last_name);'));
```

This reorganizes the list but not in alphabetical order (or any useful order as far as I can tell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my solution:

```
function dispDirectory()
{
  global $user_ID;

  // Disallow directory if there is a messaging administrator and this person is not it.
  if ($this->admin_user_id && $this->admin_user_id != $user_ID) {
    return '';
  }

    $args  = array(
        'meta_key' => 'last_name',
    );

    $wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);
    $wp_user_query->query_orderby = str_replace( 'user_login', 'wp_usermeta.meta_value', $wp_user_query->query_orderby );
    $wp_user_query->query();

    $users = $wp_user_query->get_results();


  foreach($users as $u)
  {
    $firstName = get_user_meta($u->ID, 'first_name', true);
    $lastName = get_user_meta($u->ID, 'last_name', true);         

    $directory .= '<p><strong>'.$lastName.', '.$firstName.'</strong> - <a href="'.$this->actionURL.'newmessage&to='.$u->ID.'">'.__('Send Message', 'cartpaujpm').'</a></p>';
  }
  return $directory;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

While calling `get_users()`, you can pass arguments that allows you to sort by meta values. See [this WP Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users).

An example (untested) could be:

```
$users = $this->get_users([
    'meta_key' => 'last_name',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC'
]);
```

I believe your example won't work because the property `last_name` doesn't exist on the `User` object (but rather the `User Meta`).

Comment: I believe you are right about the meta issue.  I have tried to add the arguments to get_user() as you suggest, but it does nothing to my sort.  I have seen other examples that use this and they seem to work.  I am not sure why not here.  Confusing.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @CraigTucker definitely play with the query - you'll get it right eventually. You may also need to check WP_User_Query for full documentation. What I posted should help - are you sure there's nothing else interfering after the query (between query and loop)?

Answer (score 0):

To sort get_users() by **last name**:

```
<? $users = get_users('orderby=meta_value&meta_key=last_name'); ?>
```

To sort get_users() by **last name, then first name** (if multiple users have the same last name):

```
<?
  $users = get_users(array('fields' => 'all_with_meta'));
  usort($users, function($a, $b) { if ($a->last_name.$a->first_name == $b->last_name.$b->first_name) { return 0; } return ($a->last_name.$a->first_name > $b->last_name.$b->first_name) ? 1 : -1; });
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking Etienne Dupuis solution, I added a previous meta_key called NIT, then sort the results by last_name, and it works!

```
$args = array ( 'meta_key' => 'NIT', 
                'meta_value' => $nit_user);
$users = get_users($args); 
usort(
    $users, 
    function($a, $b) { 
        if ($a->last_name.$a->first_name == $b->last_name.$b->first_name) { 
            return 0; 
        } 
        return ($a->last_name.$a->first_name > $b->last_name.$b->first_name) ? 1 : -1; 
    }
);
if ( ! empty( $users ) ) {
    foreach ( $users as  $the_user ) { 
        //...
    }
}
```